# Error regarding creating a jar file for spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, jar

I am going to create my first jar file of spark scala using IntelliJ IDEA.

I just tried to import a csv file but it is not working. Here is my code :

```scala
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

    object jar1 {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


        val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("ex1"))

        val data = sc.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv(args(0))



        data.saveAsTextFile(args(1))
      }

    }
```

When i try to package this code to create a jar file using IntelliJ IDEA,I am getting following error :

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\Users\Downloads\Count\target\scala-2.11\classes ...
[error] C:\Users\Downloads\Count\src\main\scala\jar1.scala:14:24: value read is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkContext
[error]     val data = sc.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv(args(0))
[error]                        ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

What may be the reason for this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `SparkContext` you may need to use the `textFile` method,

```scala
val data = sc.textFile(args(0))
```

But it seems a bit odd to me, it seems you are ussing the `SparkSession` syntax, I'd rather `SparkSession`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

 val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("ex1")
      .getOrCreate()
```

And here how you can read your csv

```scala
val data = spark.read.format("csv")
                     .option("header","true")
                     .option("inferSchema","true")
                     .load(args(0))
```

You can check about this [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html) and about how to read a csv [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html)

**EDIT**

To save your results:

```
data.write.format("text").save(args(1))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you include the possible alternative of how to save the final answer to a text file (data.saveAsTextFile(args(1))) in this asnwer too?

Comment: done, hope it works. If so please accept the question so any other with the same answer can quickly find a solution

Comment: Sure i will . Thank you for your solution.  Although i got an error while importing the file, that is not my main purpose. I may need to do some operation like fitting a model based on imported data.  For an example , i tried this additional code  to calculate the summary statistics and save that into a text file. : val df3 = df2.summary().show() df3.write.format("text").save(args(1)) . Now it seems that this is not working. Can you assist in that ?

Comment: Remove the show() in the first line, the show() method prints the dataframe returning nothing (Unit), so later, when you try to run a write on df3, it is not a DF but a Unit object, so there is no write method. You will need to read a little about spark in order to properly work with it, there are some links in my answer may be helpfull

Comment: HEy , I have one  last question . If i run this jar on EMR (AWS) , then should I include any additional parameters? . Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Well, the error message actually tells you why:

no `read` method in `SparkContext` class.

If you check all API `SparkContext` has to offer (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext),

won't find `read` method inside...